# Push to new Repo went wrong

Tags: git

I use Git in a simple way, so I only know what I need to know for what I do.

I have a local repo that I have been working on for some time, with a number of commits. I needed to add an additional remote repo (Github) and push to it - usually this all goes OK. For some reason it has gone weird this time and now git log is only showing commits since pushing to the new remote.

I ran git reflog (screenshot linked and text below) and can see them all there - what I want to do is revert to commit 6e7082a. I dont care about losing anything newer than that, can remove the remote repos and add them again later.

As you can see I did a hard reset to an earlier commit, which didn't really solve it, so probably best I get help before....

```
λ git reflog
73a8cb9 (HEAD -> master, Piwww/master) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{5}
9d03787 (GithubChris/master) HEAD@{1}: commit: ++dummy file created
ff6a080 HEAD@{2}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
ff6a080 HEAD@{3}: rebase: ++removed the storage oauth keys
85e43e3 HEAD@{4}: rebase: ++after experiment with dynamic components
4d2bf34 HEAD@{5}: rebase: checkout GithubChris/master
73a8cb9 (HEAD -> master, Piwww/master) HEAD@{6}: commit: ++removed the storage oauth keys
6e7082a (grafted) HEAD@{7}: commit: ++after experiment with dynamic components
7f5bc15 HEAD@{8}: commit: ++added chart period controls to abecstatus
aed0167 HEAD@{9}: commit: ++changed the algo page again
ecf757a HEAD@{10}: commit: ++created abecstatus page
d252933 HEAD@{11}: commit: ++updated algo to cleaner calcs
f518b51 HEAD@{12}: commit: ++create the Algo page
dbf4c25 HEAD@{13}: commit: ++created temp static page to test chart.js
```

Cheers

[git reflog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tSAr.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the text of your log, rather than a picture of it. This makes it easier for people to read (try looking at your question on a mobile phone).

Comment: yep, sorry. added as text

Comment: So what was the message of the commit that you want to reference? 6e7082a seems to be a commit from the repo that was shallow-fetched. When cloning, did you pass parameters like `--depth`? Did you commit _on this_ machine or on another machine and then you cloned the repo?

Comment: Check out https://ohshitgit.com/

Comment: @evolutionxbox  thanks but those examples don't cover this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you added `--depth` flag while fetching (or pulling) from remote repo as was mentioned in the comments. Label 'grafted' in log/reflog means that the commit has a parent which is not present in local repo.

So if you want to see the whole history you can run `git fetch --unshallow`

Comment: yes, I think you are right. I reset to 7f5bc15, the commit prior to that grafted commit, and I have the full history log back up to that point. There are only two commits after that I would like to get back to which for some reason are on the original remote (Piwww). I removed the second remote, so sort of getting there... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link [How to undo (almost) anything with Git](https://github.blog/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/)

1. If you want to restore the project’s history as it was at that moment in time use `git reset --hard <SHA>`
2. If you want to recreate one or more files in your working directory as they were at that moment in time, without altering history use `git checkout <SHA> -- <filename>`
3. If you want to replay exactly one of those commits into your repository use `git cherry-pick <SHA>`

Comment: I already tried a hard reset to the commit before the troubles started. my normal git log still only contains 2 entries

```λ git log --oneline

73a8cb9 (HEAD -> master, Piwww/master) ++removed the storage oauth keys
6e7082a (grafted) ++after experiment with dynamic components
```